# What is the difference between variable voltage DC output and constant voltage DC output?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, circuit-analysis, amplifier

So I want to run a (DC 19 volt input) monitor in my car.

I see two products:

DC 19 V: #1

DC 12-24V: #2

AFAIK, using a "higher voltage supply" might fry your devices.

Q1. What voltage is the second one going to deliver to my monitor?

Q2. What is the deal with "variable" voltage.

Q3. Anything else I should keep in mind?

### ====================

#1: [https://www.amazon.com/Car-Compatible-Smart-LED-Power/dp/B015H39KG4/ref=sr_1_2?crid=1R4WVF15372AY&keywords=lighter+plug+to+DC+19V&qid=1688821565&sprefix=lighter+plug+to+dc+19v%2Caps%2C1552&sr=8-2#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015H39KG4)

#2: [https://www.amazon.com/12V-24V-Charger-Power-Supply-Cable/dp/B07DKXWRVD/ref=d_pb_allspark_dp_sims_pao_desktop_session_based_sccl_4_3/145-1882937-6782930?pd_rd_w=4oDfv&content-id=amzn1.sym.6b5008ac-c24a-4aea-a3ea-015a531184f5&pf_rd_p=6b5008ac-c24a-4aea-a3ea-015a531184f5&pf_rd_r=H2BGY53TYVA9W8H5AN8K&pd_rd_wg=TSvE4&pd_rd_r=6dfc5150-03de-4110-b926-8a1db6f2b13c&pd_rd_i=B07DKXWRVD&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DKXWRVD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no indication that the second device does any converting at all.  If you plug it into a car with a 12V system, it outputs 12V.  If you plug it into a truck which runs ar 24V, you get 24V.

The first one specifically claims to output 19V.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will deliver 19v to the monitor, it has a circuit inside it to change the 12 v supply to 19v (u can just about see the sticker on the picture)
On the second one I think it just means it can deal with 12-24 volts I dont think it has a way to change the voltage itself, so with a car battery it would supply 12v

I would go with the first one, cos 12v isnt going to be enough

Comment: Connector is 12V, how can it be 24V? And if connection restricted for 5A, how possible output 20A?